# How to find equilibrium constant in reactions which have a limiting reagent?

Tags: equilibrium

> If in the following reaction
>
> $$\ce{H2 + I2 <=> 2HI}$$
>
> the initial concentrations of $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{I2}$ are $\pu{1 M}$ and $\pu{5 M}$, respectively, and at equilibrium $x$ moles of each have combined. Then what will be the $K_\mathrm{c}$ for the reaction?

What I think is that the $K_\mathrm{c}$ will not change because it does not depend on the initial concentrations of reactants and depends only on the stoichiometric equation, but the one thing I can't reason out is that those extra $4$ moles of $\ce{I2}$ should also have an affect on its equilibrium concentration (since those $4$ moles are still present in the vessel) and thus affect $K_\mathrm{c}$.

Please help me find the correct explanation for the aforesaid question.

Comment: can you just clear up what you mean by  "x moles of each have combined" do you mean the total moles at equilibrium is x or at equilibrium there is x moles of each species.

Comment: Lookup the definition of equilibrium constant and fill in the equilibrium concentrations. Then you'll get the value of the equilibrium constant.

Comment: Just how the very word "change" came about? To speak of a change, you must have some "before" and some "after". Here you don't have any "before".

Comment: If $x$ moles have combined, then there must be $2x$ moles of $\ce{HI}$, $1-x$ moles of $\ce{H2}$ and $5-x$ moles of $\ce{I2}$, so therefore $K_c$ is ...

Comment: @IvanNeretin By "change" I mean the deviation from the ideal condition where moles of $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{I2}$ are given according to the balanced equation ( 1 each in this case).

Comment: @CurtF.'s interpretation of my question is absolutely correct

Comment: There is no such thing as ideal conditions. $K_c$ is still the same constant, no matter what is the ratio of reagents.